# Hashmap unrecognized by CsvMapper

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I'm trying to serialize an object which contains a HashMap and i get following exception.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMappingException: Unrecognized column 'tags': known columns: ["_id","insertDate"] (through reference chain.
```

Also, I don't understand why it's necessary to have a schema when it's about serialization. In my mind, there is no way to have an unrecognized field because all it's specified inside the class.

Because i don't know well Jackson, i searched and tried various combination of these 2 annotations. `@JsonUnwrapped` `@JsonAnyGetter`

```
class Product{
    public @Id String _id;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private HashMap<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>();

    public String insertDate;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public HashMap<String, String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setTags(HashMap<String, String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

Code used for serialization

```
CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(Product.class).withHeader();
ObjectWriter myObjectWriter = csvMapper.writer(schema);
csvMapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.IGNORE_TRAILING_UNMAPPABLE);
csvMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
string = myObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(someProduct);
```

---

**TRY NR 2**

```
public class Product {

public @Id String _id;

public Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>();

public String insertDate;

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> getTags() {
    return tags;
}
@JsonAnySetter
public void setTags(Map<String, String> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}
```

}

**NEW ERROR**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMappingException: CSV generator does not support Object values for properties (nested Objects) (through reference chain: main.model.Product["tags"])
```

Comment: Can we look at your json?

Comment: @Coder there is no json. I created an object of type Product and try to get it in csv serialized form.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Collection` implementation class `HashMap<String, String>` for field *type* (rather than only for its initial value *type*) confuses Jackson.

Jackson checks for interface `java.util.Map` to choose proper Serializer, as evidenced in constructor of

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer

As per Schema question, according to
[jackson-dataformat-csv](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv#csv-schema-what-is-that) docs

> It is important to note that the schema object is needed to ensure
>   correct ordering of columns;
>
> Note also that while explicit type can help efficiency it is usually
>   not required, as Jackson data binding can do common
>   conversions/coercions

I guess `ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(Object)` could check reflexively to infer type for serialized object.

> Due to tabular nature of CSV format, deeply nested data structures are not well supported.

`@JsonUnwrapped` is for (nested) POJO-s only. What you want is to use `@JsonAnyGetter`. And it needs to return `java.util.Map`. JavaDocs:

> Note that the return type of annotated methods must be Map).

If you are only serializing, `@JsonAnySetter` won't be needed.

I'm curious why are you using Map for tags. Maybe `List<String> tags` would suffice, tags have only names.

Worth checking out: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object

Comment: I've tried your answer and now i get another error. Maybe i didn't understand you. Please take a look at updated question and thank you.

Comment: You can do this by creating your own schema manually instead of using the one generated by Pojo.class. Add the key fields as columns, then use @AnyGetter on the map.